# How to put special character between two columns in Latex table

Tags: tables

I want put right headed double arrow between first two columns of the table

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm,amsmath} %for mathematics %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{The Results of Granger and MWALD tests}
    \begin{tabular}{llccccc}
    \toprule
     \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Null Hypothesis} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grangers’ test (Short run)} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MWALD test (Long run)} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(r){6-7}  
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{F-Statistics}  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{p-values}  &       &\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\chi^{2}$-Statistics} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-values} \\
            \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{LTC} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{LGDP} & 7.736** & 0.021 &       & 0.169 & 0.919 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{LGDP} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{LTC} & 0.504 & 0.777 &       & 1.763 & 0.414 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{LCO2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{LGDP} & 10.829* & 0.005 &       & .324 &       & 6.490 & 0.039 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{LCO2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{LCC} & 10.673* & 0.014 &       & 7.378** & 0.025 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again (ad I did). It is better to turn your code snippet into a [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}` and including only the necessary packages. This will help who wants to answer you. `:)`

Comment: thanks @ClaudioFiandrino i am just started to use \LaTeX. do not have much knowledge about these things. from now on wards will keep this thing in mind..

Comment: Your Maximal Working Example is extremely excessive.

Comment: I hereby suggest to modify the `\multicolumn`-command to check its first argument, and if it equals `1`, it would delete itself from the source file.

Comment: For these kinds of vertically long tables, I would suggest to partition the content to, for example, groups of three rows by adding a longer vertical skip between them. This makes it easier for the eyes to keep track of the rows. This could be accomplished for example with `\\[\medskipamount]` instead of just `\\\`.

Comment: the answers have shown how to get `==>` but your table would probably look better if the numerical columns aligned on `.` you declare a decimal alignment column type but don't use it?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `@{<symbol>}` as in  `\begin{tabular}{l@{$\Longrightarrow\,\,\,$}ld{5}d{3}d{5}d{3}}`.  This won't work if you use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{LCO2}` as in the last line. I have used `dcolumn` and aligned numbers around `.` .

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3em}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{The Results of Granger and MWALD tests}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{$\Longrightarrow\,\,\,$}ld{5}d{3}d{5}d{3}}
    \toprule
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{Null} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grangers’ test (Short run)} &       \multicolumn{2}{c}{MWALD test (Long run)} \\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(r){5-6}
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{Hypothesis} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{F-Statistics}  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{p-values}  &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\chi^{2}$-Statistics} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-values} \\
            \midrule
    LTC                      & LGDP & 7.736**  & 0.021 & 0.169    & 0.919 \\
    LGDP                     & LTC  & 0.504    & 0.777 & 1.763    & 0.414 \\
    LCO2                     & LGDP & 10.829*  & 0.005 & 10.321*  & 0.006 \\
    LGDP                     & LCO2 & 1.793    & 0.408 & 3.694    & 0.158 \\
    LTC                      & LCO2 & 8.652*   & 0.013 & 5.775*** & 0.056 \\
    LCO2                     & LTC  & 6.405**  & 0.041 & 4.704*** & 0.095 \\
    LIC                      & LGDP & 5.235*** & 0.073 & 0.681    & 0.711 \\
    LGDP                     & LIC  & 1.555    & 0.460 & 3.732    & 0.155 \\
    LCO2                     & LGDP & 16.186*  & 0.000 & 8.900*   & 0.012 \\
    LGDP                     & LCO2 & 1.818    & 0.403 & 2.086    & 0.352 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{LCO2} & LCC  & 10.673*  & 0.014 & 7.378**  & 0.025 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a new column in between and populate it with the symbol you want.

How to look up a symbol?
[How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font
[Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?
[How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)