Symbol between two columns in a table
Wish to make a table with columns presenting values and their standard deviations alongside them.
For this I was planning on having a \pm symbol right in the middle between the two columns.
I tried the solution proposed in this thread but it kind of makes it pretty annoying to have to define a \multicolumn or \Block on each and every line/column.
I tried adding commands in the options of the tabular/nicematrix environment but it gets applied to every row regardless of the \Block header in the provided example below.
I thought a \newcolumntype could do the trick but all I have been able to do with it was inconclusive because I don't know how to get the spacing right between two columns.
I know an easy work around would be to have an additional column but I would really like a tight fit and I'd be surprised you could add a | between two columns but not a user-defined symbol.
This example is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{l%
        S[table-format=2.1]%
        S[table-format=1.2]}
    % Header --------   
    \toprule
    \Block[c]{2-1}{\boldmath$E_\text{cell}$} &
    \Block[c]{1-2}{\boldmath$R_{\Omega}$/ \unit{\milli\ohm}} \\
    \cmidrule(rl){2-3}
    & \Block[c]{1-1}{Value}
    & \Block[c]{1-1}{SD} \\
    % Main matter ---
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
    ($\boldsymbol{a}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 92.7 & 0.74 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 96.7 & 1.04 \\
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
    ($\boldsymbol{b}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 73.6 & 1.02 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 81.5 & 0.68 \\
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
    ($\boldsymbol{c}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 84.0 & 0.56 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 87.2 & 1.13 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Now an example of something I tried that didn't go as expected is this :
\begin{NiceTabular}{l%
        S[table-format=2.1]@{\ensuremath{\ \pm\ }}%
        S[table-format=1.2]}


I just noticed they managed to get a proper solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105997/how-to-put-special-character-between-two-columns-in-latex-table?rq=1. The difference is I am using nicematrix instead.

it's easy in a standard tabular - you just use @ , !, >, < etc. as desired (package array). presumably, you can do something similar with NiceTabular. you can get a tight fit even if you add a column, of course, because you can use the same methods to kill (or not) the standard separation between columns.

Your problem you can solve on two different way:

exploit features of siunitx package. This way is independent from table type and works on the same way at use of the nicematrix,  tabular or even tblr table.
with continuation of way as you started in your effort.

Examples which exploit siunitx features`:

with nicematrix package

\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{l  S[table-format=3.2(2),
                         separate-uncertainty]}
    \toprule
% Header --------   
$E_\text{cell}$         &   \Block{1-1}{\boldmath$R_{\Omega}$/\unit{\milli\ohm}\\
                                        Value $\pm$ SD}         \\
% Main matter ---
    \midrule
($\boldsymbol{a}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 92.3(0.74)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 96.7(1.04)                            \\
    \addlinespace
($\boldsymbol{b}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 73.6(1.02)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 81.5(0.68)                            \\
    \addlinespace
($\boldsymbol{c}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 84.0(0.56)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 87.2(1.13)                            \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


with tabular package:

\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l  S[table-format=3.2(2),
                     separate-uncertainty]}

    \toprule
% Header --------   
$E_\text{cell}$         &   {\makecell{$R_{\Omega}$/\unit{\milli\ohm}\\
                             (Value $\pm$  SD)}}                 \\
% Main matter ---
    \midrule
($\boldsymbol{a}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 92.3(0.74)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 96.7(1.04)                            \\
    \addlinespace
($\boldsymbol{b}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 73.6(1.02)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 81.5(0.68)                            \\
    \addlinespace
($\boldsymbol{c}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 84.0(0.56)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 87.2(1.13)                            \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


with tblr of tabularray:

\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l  Q[c, m, si={table-format=3.2(2),
                                       separate-uncertainty}] },  
             row{1} = {guard}  % <--
            }
    \toprule
% Header --------   
$E_\text{cell}$         &   {$R_{\Omega}$/\unit{\milli\ohm}\\
                             (Value $\pm$  SD)}                  \\
% Main matter ---
    \midrule
($\boldsymbol{a}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 92.3(0.74)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 96.7(1.04)                            \\
    \addlinespace
($\boldsymbol{b}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 73.6(1.02)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 81.5(0.68)                            \\
    \addlinespace
($\boldsymbol{c}$)      &                                       \\
\qty{1.8}{\volt}        & 84.0(0.56)                            \\
\qty{2}{\volt}          & 87.2(1.13)                            \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

At all examples are exploit the way, how to write uncertainties.
All examples gives very similar results, actually their codes differ only table specification where are used specific for used table package.


However, if I correctly understand how you like to solve your problem by insert the simbol $\pm$ between second and third column, than you can doo this for example on the following way:

\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{l%
        S[table-format=2.1]
        @{\;$\pm$\kern-0.8em}
        S[table-format=1.2]}
    % Header --------   
    \toprule
$E_\text{cell}$         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{$R_{\Omega}$/\unit{\milli\ohm}\\
                                   (Value $\pm$ SD)}}       \\     
    % Main matter ---

($\boldsymbol{a}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 92.7 & 0.74 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 96.7 & 1.04 \\
    \addlinespace 
($\boldsymbol{b}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 73.6 & 1.02 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 81.5 & 0.68 \\
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
($\boldsymbol{c}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 84.0 & 0.56 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 87.2 & 1.13 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Result is quite similar as before:

In all example I make a wee bit changes:  at \addlinespace  remove options [\arraystretch\defaultaddspace] (I didn't observe some contribution to table formatting) and remove mathbold notation for math in column headers (to my opinion it is wrong - bold variables usually denote vectors or matrices).

I actually didn't know this feature existed at all, thank you so much.

Since you are using siunitx, the S column can handle the uncertainties easily. I have slightly modified your code to get the result you want.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
  \sisetup{group-digits=false, table-format = 4.3,
           table-alignment-mode=marker, table-number-alignment=right,
           separate-uncertainty = true}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lS}
    % Header --------   
    \toprule
    {\boldmath$E_\text{cell}$} &
    {\boldmath$R_{\Omega}$/ \unit{\milli\ohm}} \\
    & {Value $\pm$ SD} \\
    \midrule
    % Main matter ---
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
    ($\boldsymbol{a}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 92.7 +- 0.74 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 96.7 +- 1.04 \\
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
    ($\boldsymbol{b}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 73.6 +- 1.02 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 81.5 +- 0.68 \\
    \addlinespace[\arraystretch\defaultaddspace]
    ($\boldsymbol{c}$) \\
    \SI{1.8}{\volt} & 84.0 +- 0.56 \\
    \SI{2}{\volt}   & 87.2 +- 1.13 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


EDIT: Sorry for pasting the wrong earlier.


Sorry, your MQWW does not produce showed image of table. It seems that is just copy of OP code from question ...

Pasted the correct code.

Now is a bit better ... Why you define three c0olumns but then use just two? Syntax for uncertainty is quite unusual, consequently the second column header is poor aligned with its column body.

Oops. Forgot to delete the extra column after editing the content :-(
